# How can I center a grid of divs (pure JS and CSS)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a pixel art maker where the user can input their own grid dimensions. I've got the grid to make itself, but I have two issues. First, I can't seem to center my grid. My grid is made up of multiple divs. I've tried:

```
grid-square {
   margin: auto;
}
```

But that spaces out all of the grid divs from each other. I can't get anything else to work. Any suggestions?

https://jsfiddle.net/2L3hjfba/2/

P.S.

Also, if the grid is too big, it makes the divs overlap, so any help with that is also appreciated!

Comment: Try to set `margin-left: 50%;` on the container of the grid

Comment: @dalelandry Editing the grid's container doesn't seem to do anything sadly since it itself is centered already. Thanks though!

Comment: What do you want when the grid is bigger than the screen? Squares have a fix width, therefore you have a limit of size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer! Each row of the grid technically took up the entire length of the container. So, I simply needed to display the rows as flex and set justify-content to center to center the whole grid.

Comment: Ooh you alreay got it (Y)

Answer (score 1):

Try This!

```
.row {
    justify-content: center;
}
```

This will help you out to center the canvas.